# Conversion between origins and coordinate systems

Tags: matrices, geometry, transformation, coordinate-systems

[Please see setup of data capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4AeM.jpg)

I have 2 data sets with coordinates of tracking a human body movement from 2 different tracking systems at the same time. One is 2 dimensional and One is 3 dimensional that obviously do not share the same origin. Therefore, for the 2D data, the coordinates are with respect to an origin A, whilst for the 3D data, the coordinates are with respect to origin B. Note that since they track the same human figure, the actual points that they refer to are the same.

I have read about transformation matrices, change of basis etc but all seem to have more information on then I have. Is there any way that I am able to shift and rotate any of the axes to get the data tracks similar I order to analyse the difference between the systems tracking errors?

Much appreciated!

Comment: You should specify what information you know and can use. What does the 2D data tracks? Is it just the projection of the 3D data in a given plane, or something else. Do you know the distance between origins, etc. If you don't give more info it will be difficult to answer your question.

Comment: @N.Bach Hi N.Bach, thanks for your attention. 

So, I do not know the distance between origins. The 2D tracks are given by a aptured video whose perpendicular to a human figure. The camera position is known with respect to the 3D origin but do not know its position from the 2D obviously.

I will update the question with the actual setup that was used to capture data. I think you will understand more than me here writing.

Also note, that the data points (coordinates) of the 2D were produced by Kinovea to which I chose a reference point from the video frame itself.(eg:bottom left corner)

Comment: The 2D discards information that’s in the 3D data. I think your best bet for comparing the two is to mathematically recreate the projection that the camera performs to create the 2D image and apply that to the 3D data.